# javascript generate video thumbnail from video url

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, canvas, html5-video

I'm going to generate video thumbnail from video url in javascript.
I need this done via ajax. 
So I followed this approach.

```
var src = thumbnail; ///video url not youtube or vimeo,just video on server
var video = document.createElement('video');

video.src = src;

video.width = 360;
video.height = 240;

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 360; 
canvas.height = 240;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
html += '<figure>';
html += '<img src="' + dataURI + '' + '" alt="' + item.description + '" />';
html += '<figurecaption>'+item.description+'</figurecaption>'
html += '</figure>';
```

But what I get is just black image. 
I guess it's because load problem but can't find a solution.
Looking forward to hearing from you.

Regards.

Comment: What type of video are you using? Does the video play correctly when you use the `<video>` tag (no canvas)?

Comment: yes. it plays really clear when I put it in html

Comment: is the video in the same origin as the page? do you see any errors/warnings/etc in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: yes,I'm working on local machine and the same virtual host.

Comment: nobody can solve this? Am I trying impossible thing?

Comment: does the video "play" inside the canvas? which "frame" do you capture? (any chance the first frame is just "black" frame?)

Comment: I checked the first frame and it's not the black image.

Comment: This is just a wild guess... but you call drawImage immediately after setting the video's src. It may take take time to load the video asset. Maybe you should try calling context.drawImage() after the video's loadeddata event?  As a lazy test, try calling video.play() video and drawing the image after a short timeout.

Comment: Not the solution to 'generate a thumbnail' but if the source is HLS and contains an audio-only rendition, you could simply use the poster image (if it exists). https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009745-CH1-AUDIOONLYSTREAM

Comment: Probably the video hasn't loaded any frame yet.
You should wait until event "loadeddata".
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadeddata) Check out this function I made based on this code (and some others from SO too) and let me know if it works for you. https://gist.github.com/tincho/6628bde69c858654d7fb79ae3eacb155 (it's plain vanilla JS -no JQuery required)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using the "loadeddata" event but I had also to add the cors attribute and play/pause the video:

```html
var video = document.createElement('video');

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  video.pause();

  var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = dataURI;
  that.css('background-image', 'url(' + dataURI + ')');
}, false);

video.preload = 'metadata';
video.muted = true;
video.playsInline = true;
video.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
video.src = $(this).data('src');
video.play();
```

Answer (score 3):

> But what I get is just black image. I guess it's because load problem but can't find a solution. Looking forward to hearing from you.

That's probably because no frame has loaded yet at the point where you're calling:

```
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

You should do that after getting some "loadeddata"  event (check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadeddata)

So your code would become:

```
var src = thumbnail; ///video url not youtube or vimeo,just video on server
var video = document.createElement('video');

video.src = src;

video.width = 360;
video.height = 240;

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 360; 
canvas.height = 240;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    html += '<figure>';
    html += '<img src="' + dataURI + '' + '" alt="' + item.description + '" />';
    html += '<figurecaption>'+item.description+'</figurecaption>'
    html += '</figure>';
});
```

Notice that this would be async so maybe you have to change what you do with that `html` variable, and instead set `image.src = dataURI;`, being `image` a reference to an Image DOM node (the one you inserted)

Answer (score 2):

You can install the npm: `video-metadata-thumbnails`, then use it like this:

```
import { getMetadata, getThumbnails } from 'video-metadata-thumbnails';

const thumbnails = await getThumbnails(blob, {
  quality: 0.6
});
console.log('Thumbnails: ', thumbnails);
```

Comment: Does'nt work on safari.